# iPhone - How to save each view controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, save

When my app's “applicationWillTerminate” function is called in the app’s delegate file I need to loop through each child controller of a tab controller and save the current state it is in. Is it possible to loop through each viewController calling a custom save function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `tabBarController.viewControllers` and send the `makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(yourCustomSaveMethod)` message to that array.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`. Much nicer than looping through your view controllers.